# Fix z-index issue in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am creating some CSS that will allow me to easily create a "breadcrumb"-like trail. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/8j3fX/27/) is a fiddler where it renders correctly. Obviously, I'm having issues with the `z-index` bug in IE8 but I using the fix listed on this [blog](http://www.brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) doesn't fix it.  My structure is a little different but all the fix does is create the IE8 bug in all the other browsers lol.

Could anyone point me in the right direction of getting this to work in IE8 and keeping it working in other browsers? (< IE8 I don't care about).

I have already added the `z-index` property to the anchor and the parent li element but it made no difference, just broke it in the other browsers.

**UPDATE**
Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/qurPf/) anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the item that comes after will overlap the one before it by default: for example, in a list, the second item would be "on top of" the first one, if they were both positioned absolutely.

Second thing is, `:after` will always be positioned "on top of" (in terms of the `z-index`) `:before` by default, so setting `z-index` on `:before` and `:after` to switch their natural positions is making extra work for yourself.

I think, therefore, that you should be able to get around the `z-index` issue in IE8 by placing the triangles not on the right of the breadcrumb item, but on the left: the second item's triangle creates the arrow for the first item, the third for the second, and so on.

Just add a `:before` and `:after` to the `ul` for the last item [on this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZtWu/) (if you want) and you should be good to go. jsFiddle isn't loading well for me in IE8, is anyone else able to check?

Comment: Genius! If I could up-vote you more I would.  Works in Chrome, IE8/9, & Firefox.